# Eclipse Adb connection error

Tags: eclipse, adb

I'm trying to run an emulator and have created multiple emulators to test my app. For some reason, after I restarted my Adb, I am getting this Connection Error. [image: As you can see, I don't know why my Adb is failing to restart.]

My emulators were working fine before I pressed to restart. I'm also using a Mac and not Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. 
For some reason ADT lost my emulator that I was using even though it was checked so I had to go to Run ->  Run Configuration then click Target and manually choose one emulator and press Run at the bottom.

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue!

Here's a link to the youtube video that I found that helped me. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PSONc6iyQQ